# Javascript - make function tell the caller when function is finished

Tags: javascript, function

So let's say I'm calling a function like so:

```
some_function('pages',{attr1: 1, attr2: 2},function(){
    alert('the function is ready!');
}
```

Now how do I set up the "some_function()" function in order to return to the caller that it is ready and make the alert go off?

Thanks :)

Comment: ... what are you doing here??

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean, but perhaps you want *a second callback* to fire when the first callback completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean callbacks.
Maybe something like this:

```
function some_function(param1, param2, callback) {

    // normal code here...

    if ( typeof callback === 'function' ) { // make sure it is a function or it will throw an error
        callback();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
some_function("hi", "hello", function () {
    alert("Done!");
}); 
/* This will do whatever your function needs to do and then,
when it is finished, alert "Done!" */
```

---

**Note:** Put your `return` after the `if` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
function some_function(type, options, callback) {
  if (some_condition) {
    callback();
  }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by some_condition. what could it be?

Comment: @AnishGupta i know that it will throw error... "some_condition" means any expression evaluation of which results to true.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the signature for `some_function` looks like this:

```
function some_function(name, data, callback)
```

You just need to call `callback` when you're ready to.

```
function some_function(name, data, callback){
    // do whatever
    if(typeof callback === 'function'){
        callback(); // call when ready
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I initiate the callback which I specify when I'm calling the function? Or will your example already do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "initiate the callback"?  My example will call the function passed as a callback.  You just need to put that `if` statement in the right spot in your method.